# Running multiple multi-container applications in a single docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run multiple containerized web apps behind a containerized reverse proxy. I am using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) as a reverse proxy and [letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) for creation, renewal, and use of Let's Encrypt certificates.

Each of the web apps has a set of dependencies (containers themself) and could be managed by one docker-compose file. However, currently, reverse proxy service, certificate service, and all web apps are in the same compose file. I just run `docker-compose up -d` and all my web apps are running.

As you see I am using docker-compose to set up my whole server infrastructure by just running one command. However, it feels a bit like I am misusing or even abusing docker-compose since I am bundling independent applications together.

Is it ok to bundle multiple containers, which do not belong together, in one docker-compose for convenience, or is there a better way to set up everything with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's totally fine and this is the purpose of docker-compose.

If you do wish kind of separation you can always split a group of containers into a separate docker-compose and run whatever you need in a single command.

For example, if you split into to groups, and name the first file as `docker-comopose-app-a.yaml` and `docker-compose-app-b.yaml` you can run them together with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-comopose-app-a.yaml -f docker-comopose-app-b.yaml up
```

**EDIT:**

You can also see the outcome before running them by changing `up` with `config` - it will print the concatenate docker-compose to stdout and detect errors if there are any.